# How to get $y(x)$ out of $y = \sqrt[3]{xa(\log_{10}(yb)-c)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to calculate the speed of a boat given the power being delivered by the motor. Unfortunately, the friction coefficient is speed dependent and is inside a $\log_{10}$. Is it possible to solve this algebraically?

$y$ is the speed, $x$ is the power, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants.

$y = \sqrt[3]{xa(\log_{10}(yb)-c)^2}$

I will try to solve it until I cannot do anymore:

$y^3 = xa(\log_{10}(yb)-c)^2$

$y^3 = xa(\log^2_{10}(yb)-2\log_{10}(yb)c+c^2)$

Now what?

Comment: Yes it is. Solve it like a normal equation, and then when you need to get rid of the base-10 logarithm, make both sides a power of 10. What I described is known as a [anti-logarithm](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55590.html).

Comment: @CaptainObvious And how do I get rid of the 10^y that appears? Do I make the logarithm of everything again? :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing a Taylor approximation to linearize the problem?

Comment: That is a good suggestion, will try and update with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For an exact solution you need to resort to the Lambert function $W$.

Your equation can be rewritten as

$$y=(p\ln(y)+q)^{2/3},$$ where $p,q$ are simple functions of $x$.

Then with $y=z^{2/3}$,

$$z=\frac23p\ln(z)+q.$$

Now let $z=-\frac23pt$ so that

$$-\frac23pt=\frac23p\ln(-\frac23pt)+q,$$

$$-t=\ln(-\frac23p)+\ln(t)+\frac{3q}{2p},$$

$$t+\ln(t)=-\frac23p\ln(-\frac23p)-\frac{3q}{2p},$$

$$te^t=\exp\left(-\frac23p\ln(-\frac23p)-\frac{3q}{2p}\right),$$

$$t=W\left(\exp\left(-\frac23p\ln(-\frac23p)-\frac{3q}{2p}\right)\right),$$

$$z=-\frac3{2p}W\left(\exp\left(-\frac23p\ln(-\frac23p)-\frac{3q}{2p}\right)\right),$$
$$y=\left(-\frac3{2p}W\left(\exp\left(-\frac23p\ln(-\frac23p)-\frac{3q}{2p}\right)\right)\right)^{3/2},$$
$$y=\left(-\frac3{2\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\ln(10)}}W\left(\exp\left(-\frac23\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\ln(10)}\ln\left(-\frac23\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\ln(10)}\right)-\frac{3\left(\sqrt{ax}\ln_{10}(b)-c\right)}{2\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\ln(10)}}\right)\right)\right)^{3/2}.$$

Sorry, there isn't simpler.

Comment: Thanks, it is simple enough as long as I can insert the Lambert function in matlab. Shouldn't be too difficult I guess.

Comment: It's available in the special functions ($\text{lambertw}$). Mind the negative sign in the log, possibly avoided by considering the negative square root.